# Why inherited variable is not initialized in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have a main UIViewController named RootViewController as

```
import UIKit
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    var amIaccessible: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

and 2 subcontrollers named oneViewController and twoViewController inheriting RootViewController as: (also read my comments)

```
import UIKit
class oneViewController: RootViewController {
    var amIaccessible: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        amIaccessible = true // I have initialized this variable of RootViewController 
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
class twoViewController: RootViewController {
    var amIaccessible: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(amIaccessible) // it should print true as initialized in oneViewController but its printing false :(
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that My oneViewController is initial view of my app and twoViewController is second view initialized after the first view, so I want RootViewController to be my singleton type controller that can hold my variables and methods throughout the app life cycle. How I can achieve this?

I don't need solution like separate singleton class, I know that way also like making a shared instance that can hold variables throughout app execution. 
So please give me solution using inheritance relation

Comment: The problem with placing variables in a view controller instead of a separate model object (which I would certainly recommend) is that you do not control the lifecycle of your view controllers. iOS creates and destroys them at will, and there is nothing you can do about that. If you want to make access to that singleton object transparent, add calculated properties or functions to your base view controller to hide the access to your centralized singleton.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding of how class inheritance works. `RootViewController` isn't a singleton. It is just a superclass of each of your two other view controllers. Each view controller has its own instance of the properties declared by `RootViewController`  Changing `super.amIaccessible` in one view controller instance won't change its value in another.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the some things you should look into this

```
class oneViewController: RootViewController {
var amIaccessible: Bool = false // here you are overridding the amIaccessible property. so if you will use this with oneViewController object it will always gives you overridden property value

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    amIaccessible = true // here you are changing the overridden amIaccessible property value. if you want to change super class propert value you should use super keyword.
    print(self.amIaccessible) // true
    print(super.amIaccessible) // false


   // for e.g  super.amIaccessible = true // in the same way access it with super keyword.
 }
}
```

and if in `twoViewController` if you want to access amIaccessible  property of `RootViewController` you have to use super with property and if you change  value of amIaccessible property from `oneViewController` you can't get the same value in `twoViewController` because for every object iOS creates new property and kill them when it deallocates from memory.

```
class twoViewController: RootViewController {
var amIaccessible: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(super.amIaccessible) // it will always gives you false
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, to access RootViewController variables in other viewcontrollers then I should make them static like:

```
import UIKit
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    static var amIaccessible: Bool = false  // make this static

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

access amIaccessible of parent class as RootViewController.amIaccessible

```
import UIKit
class oneViewController: RootViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        RootViewController.amIaccessible = true // I have initialized this variable of RootViewController 
    }
}

import UIKit
class twoViewController: RootViewController {
    var amIaccessible: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(RootViewController.amIaccessible) // it is printing true now
    }
}
```